# Apache SetEnv works in one context but not another

Tags: apache-http-server

I'm using Apache 2.4.37 Windows an I have an `.htaccess` file with this line:

```
SetEnv site_path c:\wamp64\www\test_folder
```

If I access the site from

```
http://test_folder
```

And echo `$_SERVER`, `site_path` shows up. However, if I access the same page from a phone by IP address over Wi-Fi (`http://192.168.215.151`), the `site_path` variable doesn't show at all.

I also tested using the `SetEnv` in the `httpd-vhosts.conf` file and got the exact same result.

Why would `site_path` only show up in the first scenario?

Comment: Where are you setting `SetEnv`? In the context of a virtual host config in your `httpd.conf` or somewhere else?

Comment: I tried both the .htaccess file and the httpd-vhosts.conf file. I mentioned this in the question above.